# understanding algebraic division of generic functions a la Silvanus P Thompson

Tags: functions, polynomials

Can someone help me understand what Silvanus P. Thompson is doing, specifically with algebraic division?

He's explaining how we establish the quotient rule for differentiation.

Given
$y = \frac{u}{v}$ and $y+dy =\frac{u + du}{v + dv}$

[image]

Is this some old fashioned notation? I haven't found anything on Google or YouTube or here that helps.

Would Gardner's edition explain this perchance?